# Yii - what to pass as an argument when key-value pair is used in Yii extension ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Now , I created two dropdownlists (min and max) using the below code.

```
<?php
                    $this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attribute' => 'min',                        'data'=>array('100000.0'=>'1lakh','200000.0'=>'2lakh','300000.0'=>'3lakh','400000.0'=>'4lakh'),                              
    'assoc'=>true,                    

                    'options' => array(
          'onSelect' => 'cost_change(item.value);',
                        'allowText' => false,
                    ),                  
                    'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Min Cost', 'style'=>'width:30px'),
                ));                
                ?>
```

```
<?php
            $this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'max',
'data' => array('300000.0'=>'3lakh','400000.0'=>'4lakh','500000.0'=>'5lakh','600000.0'=>'6lakh'),   
                'options' => array(                       
                    'allowText' => false,                       
                ),                   
                'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Max Cost', 'style'=>'width:30px'),
            ));               

            ?>
```

I'm calling a script on selecting the min value which in turn calls the script

```
 <script>

        function cost_change(price) {
            var value = price;
            console.log("value",value);     
              jQuery('#max').html( jQuery('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').html())
            var toKeep = jQuery('#max').filter( function( ) {
                return parseInt(this.value) > parseInt( value);       
         } );        
           console.log("to keep",toKeep);
           jQuery('#max').html(toKeep);
        }
        </script>
```

Now my problem is when I select 1lakh as min value in dropdown, 1lakh is passed to script instead of 100000.0. What should I pass to the function cost_change to pass 100000.0 instead of 1lakh.

Answer (score 0):

The default combobox doesn't support associative arrays. However, there's a fix for this at https://github.com/kanyuga/yii-combobox/blob/master/EJuiComboBox.php

**EDIT**
Also I stopped using this extension and use http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/ instead.

Comment: Hello Topher, glad you answered my question. But, I changed the same thing in my EJuiComboBox.php. Now, when i select a value (i used ite.value to pass) the text is passed and sometimes undefined is passed.

Comment: Also topher, the dropdown works perfectly with array of only values, but why not with array of key-value pairs

Comment: Hmm. You should note that the `id` of the select is now `#{model}_{attribute}`. Also I'd try `$("#SelectForm_min").onChange(function(){cost_change($(this).val())});`.

Comment: `<select id="SearchForm_max_cost" name="SearchForm[max_cost]" style="display: none;">
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="0">300000.0</option>
<option value="1">400000.0</option>
<option value="2">500000.0</option>
<option value="3">600000.0</option>
</select>` In this I want to pass 1 and not 400000.0. If I give `item.value` 400000.0 is passed, I want to pass 1 what should I give now